# HiQPDF Navigation Error on some environments

Tags: c#, security, iis, pdf-generation, hiqpdf

I am doing URL to image conversion using HiQPDF. The conversion works on localhost. It also works on AWS when the hosted application is opened from browser. It doesn't work on other environments like my personal computer and another machine where I am logging in using VPN, on any browser. ConvertURLToImage(url) throws this error - 
"Navigation error. The remote server closed the connection before the entire reply was received and processed."

I don't think it has got to do with any IIS settings otherwise it wouldn't have worked on AWS.

I have added the following in Web.Config for access to my URL -

```
   <location path="export/execReportDashlets">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="?" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
   </location>
```

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into the same "Navigation error..." message while trying to generate a PDF. We are using version 8.10 of the HiQPdf software, which is working fine for some connections and has started failing for others. After digging into the issue I believe our problems are related to SSL/TLS connections. On our newer servers we don't allow anything below TLS 1.1, if we relax those rules the connections are successful. I upgraded HiQPdf to version 10.17 and ran some tests. Connections using the updated component are working fine with our newer server configuration. There doesn't appear to be any mention of updates having to do with secure connections on their site though and both versions are using the same runtime version. I have a support request in with them to confirm, but I think upgrading will fix the issue for us.

Maybe relevant, maybe not, depends on the request.

**Update:**
HiQPdf support got back to me with the following:

The latest version should work with TLS 1.1 and 1.2. You can try the latest version in demo mode if you don’t set a serial number.